How do I modify the width of the password component in PrimeVue?
I am trying to override the default width of the Password component in PrimeVue but it didn't work.
**I have attempted to override the width using the following CSS:
**
.p-password-input {
width: 100%
}
or
.p-password.has(.p-password-toggle-mask-icon) .p-password-input {
width: 100%
}

You can apply the width directly in the template using inline styles like this:
<Password 
  v-model="password" 
  :feedback="false" 
  placeholder="Password" 
  :style="{ width: '100%' }" 
  :inputStyle="{ width: '100%' }" 
/>

You can also set the width using CSS classes, like this:
<Password 
  v-model="password" 
  :feedback="false" 
  placeholder="Password" 
  class="full-width" 
/>

<style>
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width .p-inputtext {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>


p-password-input is the class for input element. The class for root element is p-password, which is inline.
It should be:
.p-password,
.p-password-input { width: 100% }

This is solved without modifying styles by adding fluid prop to Password:

Spans 100% width of the container when enabled.

